# express-jwt setting user object to req.user._doc instead of just req.user?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, express-jwt

I've used the npm package express-jwt in the past for easy JWT signing, decoding, etc. Usually (and [according to the docs](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt)) it intercepts a request, decodes the token with the user object payload and sets `req.user` to that payload. However, this time around it's showing that `req.user` looks like this:

```
{ '$__': 
   { strictMode: true,
     getters: {},
     wasPopulated: false,
     activePaths: { paths: [Object], states: [Object], stateNames: [Object] },
     emitter: { domain: null, _events: {}, _maxListeners: 0 } },
  isNew: false,
  _doc: 
   { __v: 0,
     password: '$2a$10$ypbCbWsEA7W17IQjdox5Oe..MhhCco/0yIw.J1Y6m6vJDllCB0LLS',
     username: 'b',
     lastname: 'Last',
     firstname: 'First',
     _id: '56969210e3f8bf2ab9aee66d' },
  _pres: { '$__original_save': [ null, null, null ] },
  _posts: { '$__original_save': [] },
  iat: 1452709101 
}
```

Instead of just:

```
{
    __v: 0,
    password: '$2a$10$ypbCbWsEA7W17IQjdox5Oe..MhhCco/0yIw.J1Y6m6vJDllCB0LLS',
    username: 'b',
    lastname: 'Last',
    firstname: 'First',
    _id: '56969210e3f8bf2ab9aee66d'
}
```

I'm trying to figure out why this time around I need to specify `req.user._doc` to get the specific info about the user. I've compared my code at every source and it's practically identical to a past project, and I just tested them side by side - one project sets req.user to the user object, the other sets req.user to the object shown above, where the user object can only be found in the `_doc` property.

I checked what is actually getting returned from the mongoose `.findOne()` method in both projects and it *is* the larger object shown above in both projects, but express-jwt seems to be weeding out the extra stuff automatically in one project but not in the other.

I've also noticed that the JWT with all the additional info I don't want is much longer than the JWT on the project with the correct `req.user` object. So perhaps that means something weird is happening when the JWT is getting signed with the payload...

Here's the relevant code from the one that is requiring `req.user._doc`:

#### server.js

```
...
var expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
var authRoutes = require('./routes/authRoutes');
var nationRoutes = require('./routes/nationRoutes');
...
app.use('/api', expressJwt({ secret: config.secret }));
app.use('/api/nation', nationRoutes);
app.use('/auth', authRoutes);
...
```

#### authRoutes.js

```
...
authRouter.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) res.status(500).send(err);
        if (!user) res.status(401).send('The username you entered does not exist');
        else if (user) {
            bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, function (err, match) {
                if (err) throw (err);
                if (!match) res.status(401).send("Incorrect Password");
                else {
                    var token = jwt.sign(user, config.secret);
                    res.send({
                        user: user,
                        token: token
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
...
```

#### nationRoutes.js (where the problem is manifesting itself)

By this point, express-jwt has decoded the token and (supposedly) set the token's payload (which is supposed to be just the user's info, not the additional `$__`, etc. stuff) to `req.user`, but I'm having to do `req.user._doc` as shown in the code below to get it to work.

```
...
nationRouter.route('/')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        console.log(req.user);  // Shows the larger object with added stuff from above
        Nation.find({ user: req.user._doc._id }, function (err, nations) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send(err);
            }
            res.send(nations);
        });
    })
...
```

In case it's helpful, or possibly part of the problem, here is the user model and the nation model:

#### user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

var userSchema = new Schema({
    firstname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: String
});

userSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
    var user = this;

    if (!user.isModified("password")) {
        next();
    }

    bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function (err, hash) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        user.password = hash;
        next();
    }); 
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

#### nation.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Nation = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    creationDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Nation', Nation);
```

Comment: did you find why is this happening?

Comment: @amit, check my updated answer below, as well as the links to the conversations on their github issues page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I played around with past version numbers of the `jsonewebtoken` package in my code and the problem goes away with version 5.5.1. (5.5.2 seems to have introduced the problem). I looked into the source code for jsonwebtoken, and had a couple conversations with some of the developers on their github issues page ([here](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/156) and [here](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/159)). It seems like they introduced a package called `xtend` to the payload in the `jwt.sign()` method, which seems to be adding all the additional meta properties onto the payload before encoding.

I'm using Mongoose, and according to one of the `jsonwebtoken` developers, I will need to begin using the `Document.toObject()` method from Mongoose. So from now on:

```
...
jwt.sign(user.toObject(), ...)
...
```

will be the way to do this in Mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `"express-jwt": "^8.4.1"` I was able to get the JWT's object with:

```js
import { expressjwt } from 'express-jwt';

...

const jwtObject = req.auth;
console.log(jwt)
// { "iat": 123124, "exp": 1234521, "userId": "511a...", ... }
```